# HowTo create custom MaxLength and Required validation with new error message, logic stays the same

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
[MaxLength(45, ErrorMessage = Translations.Attribute.MAX_LENGTH)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = Translations.Attribute.REQUIRED)]
```

How can I create custom `Required` and `MaxLength` validation with default translated message. Can I simply override it and change just errorMessage?

I just want to write

```
[MyMaxLength(45)]
[MyRequired]
```

Solution for requied founded:

```
public class MyRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
    {
        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Polje {0} je obvezno", name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to localise the error message?

Comment: Can't see better option than using ErrorMessageResourceType and ErrorMessageResourceName parameters for this validators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to just derive from `MaxLengthAttribute`, or whatever other attributes you are using...

```
public class MyMaxLengthAttribute : MaxLengthAttribute
{
    public MyMaxLengthAttribute(int length) : base(length)
    {
        ErrorMessage = Translations.Attribute.MAX_LENGTH;
    }

    // other ctors/members as needed
}
```

Comment: This will take care of the server side validation but you won't have any client jquery validation.   You need to also create a MyMaxValidator if you are using MVC

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is using MVC and wants a custom or localized MaxLength error message.

1) Create your own MaximumLengthAttribute derived from MaxLength that uses a  resource file.

2) Create a MaximumLengthValidator that exploits the MaxLength rules.

3) Register your MaximumLenghtAttribute and Validator in the Application_Start

4) Decorate your property with the MaximumLength(45) attribute.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class MaximumLengthAttribute : MaxLengthAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MaxLength with a custom and localized error message
    /// </summary>
    public MaximumLengthAttribute(int maximumLength) : base(maximumLength)
    {
        base.ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaximumLength";
        base.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources);
    }
}
```

and.....

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
public class MaximumLengthValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator
{
    private string _errorMessage;
    private MaximumLengthAttribute _attribute;

    public MaximumLengthValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, MaximumLengthAttribute attribute)
    : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
        _errorMessage = attribute.FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName());
        _attribute = attribute;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            // Uses MVC maxlength validator (but with a custom message from MaximumLength)
            ErrorMessage = this._errorMessage,
            ValidationType = "maxlength"
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("max", _attribute.Length);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

and in Application_Start...

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(MaximumLengthAttribute), typeof(MaximumLengthValidator));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I created the AppMaxLength attribute was inheriting from MaxLengthAttribute, the MaxLength not fixing, it can be change on the webconfig or DBConfig if you want.

```
public class AppMaxLengthAttribute : MaxLengthAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public AppMaxLengthAttribute(string configName)
    : base(int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configName]))
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "maxlength"
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("max", this.Length);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

AND the applying:

```
    [AppMaxLength("NotFixedCodeLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MsgMaxLength")]       
    public string Code { get; set; }
```

The config info on webconfig:

appSettings tag insert the key

```
<add key="NotFixedCodeLength" value="10" />
```

Sorry my Eng not good. =))

Comment: Can you add some more context around your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;        

[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required!!!")]
[MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Max number of characters is 30 duh!")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```